# POST request not getting mapped to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, angular-promise

I am sending a POST request from Angularjs $http service . It is working fine when my promise is like below and is getting properly mapped to Spring Controller ,

**service.js**

```
reassignKsaPendingLeads : function(data,username)
                                    {
    var promise = $http({
        url : "reassignPendingLeads.htm",
        method : "POST",
        data : mydata
        })
        .success(function(data, status, header, config, statusText)
        {
        }       
}
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping({ "reassignPendingLeads.htm" })
    public @ResponseBody String updateAccessStatus(@RequestBody List<KsaLead> ksaLeads) 
    {
        log.info("Inside updateAccessStatus");
        return "true";
    }
```

The json object i pass from service.js is getting mapped properly to @RequestBody List ksaLeads.
Since the json object contains same keys as bean properties of KsaLead.

But Now i want to pass another parameter **username** apart from json body       (data).
Then i get Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring Controller .

**new service.js**

```
reassignKsaPendingLeads : function(data,username)
                                    {
                                        var mydata = JSON.stringify(data) + '&username=' + username;    
                                        var promise = $http({
                                            url : "reassignPendingLeads.htm",
                                            method : "POST",
                                            data : mydata
                                        })
                                        .success(function(data, status, header, config, statusText)
                                        {
                                        }
```

**new Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping({ "reassignPendingLeads.htm" })
    public @ResponseBody String updateAccessStatus(@RequestBody List<KsaLead> ksaLeads,@RequestParam String username) 
    {
        log.info("Inside updateAccessStatus");
        return "true";
    }
```

Can anyone guide me as to how should i pass data from angularJs so that it gets mapped correctly to Spring Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you want to pass the username as a request parameter. In order to do this, the `$http` can have a `params` input field:

```
function(data,username) {
    var promise = $http({
        url: "reassignPendingLeads.html",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        params: { username: username }
    })
// continue with your promise here
}
```

If you want to pass it inside the request body we have to do the following steps:

We have to add the `username` to the `mydata` object.

```
// we assume that data is not a primitive type
function(data,username) {
    var mydata;
    // check if data is defined
    if (data) {
        // make a deep copy first, since we don't want to modify the input
        mydata = angular.copy(data);
    } else {
        // if the data is undefined, create e new object
        mydata = {};
    }
    // add the username to mydata
    mydata.username = username;
    var promise = $http({
        url: "reassignPendingLeads.html",
        method: "POST",
        data: mydata
    })
// continue with your promise here
}
```

On the back-end we have to make sure that we can accept this kind of data. For this it is advised to create a data class which holds the username and any other fields which may appear on your `data` object from the front-end.
Probably something like this:

```
public class MyDataClass {
    private String username;
    // other fields

    // no args constructor
    public MyDataClass() {}

    // all args constructor
    public MyDataClass(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

   // getter and setters 
}
```

Now we modify the controller to accept it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reassignPendingLeads.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String updateAccessStatus(@RequestBody MyDataClass data) 
    {
        log.info(data.getUsername());
        return "true";
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Ervin Szilagyi , Thank You .Your Answer worked .But if i want to pass another JsonObject in body then ?

Comment: Edited my answer to handle this as well.